# Uploading a file from a .NET client to PHP on a server

Tags: php, .net, http

I'd like to use .NET to upload a picture file from the local disk to a web server where it will be received by a PHP script and saved to the server. I'm not sure of the preferred way to transfer the data, now that I've realised it isn't as simple as I'd hoped.

The problem is that PHP's file upload mechanism only accepts data encoded as `multipart/form-data`, and I can't see a way to get WebClient to upload the file this way without doing the encoding myself into a byte array and uploading that.

Which would be the neater solution: should I go through the hassle of doing this encoding on the client? Or, if I just use `WebClient.UploadFile`, should I be able to receive it from `php://input` and, if so, will it need decoding?

I have found several examples of doing the encoding, on this and other sites, so I don't need help with that. I'd just like an opinion on whether such client-side encoding is sensible or necessary, or whether I can do the work on the server instead by not using `$_FILES` and receiving the data in a more 'manual' way.

In the longer term I will be seeking to better understand the HTTP protocol.

Comment: what you really want to achieve? uploading can be done by many ways but it depends on what you want to do

Comment: I'd like to use .NET to upload a picture file from the local disk to a web server in a way suitable for being received by PHP and saved to the server.

Comment: The easiest way to upload a file to PHP is to use the PUT HTTP method. I don't know what kind of HTTP libraries there are in .NET, but on the PHP end you can get a PUT'ed file from php://input. No encoding needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out my own answer, thanks to Janoszen's comment. Just the kind of simplicity I wanted.

Here's an extract from the .NET client (example in Visual Basic):

```
Dim wc As New WebClient()
wc.UploadFile(url, "PUT", filename)
```

And from the PHP on the server:

```
file_put_contents(filename, file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Thanks Janoszen!